# Running a hadoop job using java command

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a simple java program that sets up a MR job. I could successfully execute this in Hadoop infrastructure (hadoop 2x) using 'hadoop jar '. But I want to achieve the same thing using java command as below.

java className

1. How can I pass hadoop configuration to this className?
2. What extra arguments do I need to supply?
3. Any link/documentation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you run your 'hadoop jar' command with the other parameters, same way you can run using java.

check if, this commands evaluates to hadoop class path

```
$ hadoop classpath
```

then whatever your custom jar is should be added in class path

```
$ java -cp `hadoop classpath`:/my/tools/jar/tools.jar
```

I am able to get mine working with this, on my hadoop cluster

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find a documentation on this. hadoop command is a script, a lot of classes are used there eg. Class for accessing filesystem FsShell, class used when we run a jar RunJar etc. Adding hadoop related libraries, configuration files to classpath are handled in the hadoop command itself.

You better take a look at the hadoop script.

Answer (score 0):

How can you do that? Any jar file execution means, it has to execute in distributed environment where all daemons work together to complete the execution.
We are not running locally or on local file system. So, it needs be executed as per the norms of hdfs so i don't think we can execute like we do in local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is a framework which simplifies the distributed computing. Before hadoop also, programmers know about parallel processing and multi threading concepts. But when you deal with multiple machines you need to know how to

1. Communicate between machines
2. Network processing
3. What if one machine fails? fault tolerance
   and many more! which is a huge, that's where hadoop simplifies your job. It takes care of all your operating level stuff and you can focus on just your business logic.

So in your case, based on what you are asking, there is no direct answer for that. Because by passing parameters the your program doesn't work. You will need to write lot of libraries to deal with distributed computing. If you want to explore them, then I would suggest go ahead and read hadoop source code.

```
http://hadoop.apache.org/version_control.html
```